# Magento 2.1.5 How to create Module which can use Eav functionalities (addAttribute in my case)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, eav, create-product

I want to make module that creates magento products from xml file. So I have module with command `php bin/magento LCB:import path/to/xml`. It loads xml file with custom attributes which need to be created. I know how create attribute via InstallData.php or UpgradeData.

I need

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute()
```

function in my Model. Is it even possible to extend Model in this way?

I didn't found anything useful in my case. Below is my code. I have errors in:

```
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
```

The problem is that:

$eavSetup requeres $setup

$setup requires $resource

$resource requires something with Interface and so on... still doesn't work

Code:

```
namespace LCB\Import\Model;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Setup\Module\Setup\ResourceConfig;
use Magento\Setup\Module\ConnectionFactory;
use magento\framework\App\DeploymentConfig;
use magento\framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use magento\framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool;
use magento\framework\Filesystem\DriverPool;

class Importer
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $objectManager;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $this->eavSetupFactory = new EavSetupFactory($this->objectManager);
}

public function createAttribute($attributes)
{

    $dirList = new DirectoryList(BP);
    $driverPool = new DriverPool();
    $configFilePool = new ConfigFilePool();
    $Reader = new Reader($dirList, $driverPool, $configFilePool);
    $DeploymentConfig = new DeploymentConfig($Reader);
    $ConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    $ResourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
    $resource = new ResourceConnection($ResourceConfig, $ConnectionFactory, $DeploymentConfig);
    $setup = new Setup($resource);

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute){

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attribute,
        [
            'type'                    => 'text',
            'backend'                 => '',
            'frontend'                => '',
            'label'                   => $attribute,
            'input'                   => '',
            'class'                   => '',
            'source'                  => '',
            'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible'                 => true,
            'required'                => false,
            'user_defined'            => false,
            'default'                 => '',
            'searchable'              => false,
            'filterable'              => false,
            'comparable'              => false,
            'visible_on_front'        => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique'                  => false,
            'apply_to'                => ''
        ]
    );
}
}
}
```

## Main question is:

How to implement addAttribute() function from eav in my Model or it is not possible?

## Edit:

@B G Kavinga I tried to do like this even earlier. Let try this way. I type command LCB:import then execute() function from my command class is called. In this function new Importer is created then I need to call createAttribute();

If not in createAttribute() function, I need to create eavSetup in my Command Class when I create new Impoter. So I need to create $eavSetupFactory, $setup and $setup requires ModuleDataSetupInterface and so on...

I need to create whole $eavSetupFactory properly. Which requires a lot od dependencies. So I need to create about 20 or even more "new" objects (I guess it is not a good practice). So how to implement this $eavSetupFactory in a right way?

Here is the mentioned execute function:

```
class ImportCommand extends Command
{
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $eavSetupFactory = new EavSetupFactory($objectManager);

        $context = new Context(); //Context requires a lot of dependencies and dependencies requires other too
        $setup = new DataSetup($context); //requires ModuleDataSetupInterface

        $Importer = new Importer($eavSetupFactory, $setup);
        //load attributes
        $Importer->createAttribute($attributes);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the new keyword to create an object, instead inject required object using the constructor. Read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html 
Try following code:

```
<?php


namespace BGKavinga\Examples\Model;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class Importer
{
/**
 * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
 */
private $setup;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->setup = $setup;
}

/**
 * @param $attributes
 */
public function createAttribute($attributes)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->setup]);

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attribute,
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => $attribute,
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

}

Check module here. https://github.com/bgkavinga/sample-code/raw/master/magento2-create-product-attributes.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still cant use it. If you can check my question again I've added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

@B G Kavinga thank you, your answer brought me on right way. I don't know if it is good solution but it works for me. I just added to my ImportCommand constructor like this.

```
use LCB\Import\Model\Importer;

class ImportCommand extends Command
{

private $importer;

    public function __construct(Importer $importer)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->importer = $importer;
    }
}
```